# Can two players tie for first place in Hearts?

Tags: house-rules, hearts

At Pagat's website, it says game of Hearts (the card game) ends when a player reaches 100 points or more: http://www.pagat.com/reverse/hearts.html#scoring

This implies that the game ends even if two players are tied for first place. I've always played it this way.

But recently someone told me that they use a rule so that you must continue playing until there is a single first-place finisher (i.e. single low-scorer).

Is there a clear rule for this, or does it vary a lot?

Comment: What is wrong with having to players tied for first place? I have never played with a version where you play until not tied as that could make a game go on for a long time until one of those players scores more points than the other player.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with tying, from my point of view! So I can't defend the other position. But since someone told me about this alternate way of scoring, I wondered how popular it was.

Comment: I would guess it is not that common since in hearts you are really playing to avoid losing rather than win

Comment: Something to remember it seems a lot of people do have problems with ties as they try to get ties out of many events as possible, one example would be all the over time they put in sports to prevent a tie.

Comment: I found it interesting that you said "you are really playing to avoid losing" about Hearts. There seem to be two camps about this. Some people play to avoid losing, but others do play to win! And they get very frustrated by the people who play to just avoid losing.

Comment: I will just say this, if the object is to win then why is the end of the game triggered by someone getting a losing score. In most other card games where the end is triggered by a score it is a winning score not a losing score.

Comment: I don't think of 100 as being a "losing" score. It is just the signal that the game has ended. Suppose at the end of the game, 2 players are over 100 and 2 players are under. Are the 2 latter players winners, while the former are losers? No, the rules say that the lowest scoring player is **the** single winner. From my perspective, if the point of the game is to heap points on a single player, then you're probably going to wind up with 3 players who come in below 100 and 1 who is above. If you say those 3 players are "winners" then it doesn't sound like a challenging (or fun) game to me.

Comment: Why does there have to be a single person who wins for a game to be fun?

Comment: Everyone has their own idea of fun - it's just a matter of opinion. But for me, if 3/4 players are winners and 1 person is the loser, then it just doesn't seem like much of a challenge - rather it seems like a game designed to have 3 people gang up on a 4th person, rather unpleasant all around imho. All of the players except for one are winners? I am trying to think of any other games that have rules like that... but I can't come up with any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot recall encountering this situation. I reckon that ties are not common, and that there is not a clear rule.

How it is handled would depend on the scoring system in use. For example, the description in [Hoyle](https://books.google.com.au/books?isbn=0307486095) lists three settlement methods: "Cumulative scoring" and "Howell Settlement" avoid the issue, whereas in the "Sweepstake" method, if two players are clear then they divide the pot.

Pagat does refer to it in the section about [variations of scoring](http://www.pagat.com/reverse/hearts.html#vars_scoring). It does say "may" continue, so i suppose that each game should declare whether the low points are shared or whether the game plays on. (Pagat does not mention those other settlements.)

> If a player reaches or exceeds 100 points and there is a tie for low score, additional hands may be played until there is a clear winner.

In real life games, we did not bother with settlement: as soon a someone blew it, then end of game, move on to the next. Online games would need to utilise settlements, especially if doing rating.

Do you have any statistics from your online game, regarding how often this situation occurs?

Comment: Hi David, I don't have stats for this, but I agree that it would be interesting to record it. I will look into doing this!

Comment: At my site, when two people tie, the rating is just computed as a tie for the two winning players. Elo ratings were developed for chess, where a stalemate is possible... so this is something that the ratings system can handle.

Answer (score 5):

Ties can be relatively common in Hearts, depending on the difference in skill levels between participating players. If you're playing for fun it might not seem right. If you're playing for wagers, it simply means that those who are tied receive an equal share of the pot.

As Joe W points out in his comment, you can 'win' at hearts by not losing. This can lead to 3 players pinning nearly all the points on a single, weaker player. I've played on a site where this was common practice, the remaining 3 would usually be very close to each other in terms of scoring and occasionally tie for first (or second) place. There is no real incentive to break this tie position.

Comment: Most people I've played with have been vehemently opposed to the idea that you win at Hearts by avoiding losing. The general idea is that there's [only 1 winner in Hearts](http://worldofcardgames.com/hearts-card-game-strategy-tips.html), and you are not a winner if you come in 2nd, 3rd, or 4th. People who subscribe to this rule get very frustrated at the ones who think they are "winning" by piling points on the person with the highest score. It doesn't seem like much of a game if your chances of winning are 3 in 4.